# Difference between production and test environment in behavior of a method

Tags: java, spring, authentication

Ive got strange problem. There is a given method that saves user to the database or updates when a given user exists. There is double request (almost simultaneously) with the same user (I cant change that).
In a local environment this piece of code works as expected when given user doesn't exists a new User is created and then second request with same data goes without problem (findByIamNumberAndUpdate -> userRepository::save). User is found in database and updated (as expected). However in a production environment the second try with the same user leads to problems  . Application behaves as if the first user wasn`t created and I get *duplicate key value violates unique constrain exception*. There is attempt to create two users.
Any help appreciated :)

````
@Transactional
public Buyer upsertUser(User user) {
        String userEmail = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(user.getUsername().toLowerCase());
        return findByIamNumberAndUpdate(user, userEmail)
                .or(() -> findByEmailAndUpdate(user, userEmail))
                .map(userRepository::save)
                .orElseGet(() -> newUser(user, userEmail));
    }```
````

Comment: Sounds like your production application has multiple threads to handle requests, while your local dev version doesn't.

Comment: tbh I think the same but my techlead insists that the reason behind it is different, so I want to find out what are the other possible causes

Comment: 2 request with same data, 1 is always first. You are checking at the same moment both think user doesn't exist, both try to create a new one, only one will succeed. The checks aren't fool proof and will fail in just this scenario and is what you encounter. Instead of checking, catch the duplicate key exception and handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You told us nothing about your production environment. But that's okay, we can just presume that it is another one of those extremely complex java web application servers with a deep stack full of layers of... stuff.

In such scenarios you have to always be concerned with concurrency.

You cannot just execute statements assuming that no other statement will happen to execute between them, you cannot execute event handlers in a certain order and assume that their side-effects will be applied on the server in the same order, etc.   Quite often, you cannot even assume that data which was just written by one event handler is visible by another.

In your scenario your complex stack is probably caching the database writes somewhere, perhaps on a per-thread basis, perhaps on a per-process basis. You may have thousands of threads, dozens of processes, and each time a request comes in it probably gets processed by one of them at random. So, your two attempts to add a user may be executed in any random order, and in largely disparate data spaces.

To avoid this, various special constructs must be utilized for performing any work which involves writing to a database (and some that involve reading) for guaranteeing that it will be performed atomically, and for guaranteeing the consistency of the data across request handlers. For example, database transactions. Other constructs that might be available to you depend on your specific stack.